# JavaScript image loader isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make really simple image loader for my game but I can't find out why this isn't working.. Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var images = [];

    function loadImages(imageFiles) {
        var loadedImages = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < imageFiles.length; i++) {
            var image = new Image();

            image.onload = function() {
                alert("Loaded");
            }

            image.src = imageFiles[i];
            loadedImages[i] = image;
        }

        return loadedImages;
    }

    function init() {
        images = loadImages(['img/1.png', 'img/2.png']);

        main();
    }

    function main() {  
        ctx.drawImage(images[1], 0,0);  
    }

    init();
}
```

All I see is blank canvas without an image.

Comment: because images are loaded asynchronously and you treat it as a synchronous operation.

Comment: check whether you are providing the right path for image, better you should also check whether the images are being added to DOM or not

Answer (score 1):

> Use [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), The Promise object is used for deferred and asynchronous computations. A Promise represents an operation that hasn't completed yet, but is expected in the future.

**[`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)**, *The `Promise.all(iterable)` method returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved.*

```js
function loadImages(imageFiles) {
  var promiseArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < imageFiles.length; i++) {
    var eachPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var image = new Image();
      image.onload = function() {
        alert('Loaded!');
        resolve();
      }
      image.src = imageFiles[i];
    });
    promiseArr.push(eachPromise);
  }
  return promiseArr;
}

function init() {
  var AllImages = ['https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/earth-day-2016-5741289212477440.2-5643440998055936-ror.jpg', 'https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/earth-day-2016-5741289212477440.3-5700735861784576-ror.jpg'];
  var allPromises = loadImages(AllImages);
  Promise.all(allPromises).then(function() {
    alert('All Loaded');
    main();
  });
}

function main() {}
init();
```

Comment: Best solution in my opinion. Promises are the way to go. +1

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
image.onload = function() {
                alert("Loaded");
            }
```

with

```
if(i==1){
    image.onload = function() {
                    main();
                }}
```

when the second image is loaded, your function is called
then edit the code to suit your needs
I will edit more in a while

Answer (score 0):

Images are loaded asynchronously so when you try to read the file in main, the image still is loading. So you need to wait until all the images are loaded.

```
window.addEventistener("load", function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var images = [];

    function loadImages(imageFiles, completeFnc) {
        var loadedImages = [],
            loadedCnt = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < imageFiles.length; i++) {
            var image = new Image();

            image.onload = function() {
                loadedCnt++;  //increment the count
                if(loadedCnt==imageFiles.length) {  //if count equals total, fire off callback
                    completeFnc();
                }
            };

            image.onerror = function () {
                alert("There was a problem loading the images");
            };

            image.src = imageFiles[i];
            loadedImages[i] = image;
        }

        return loadedImages;
    }

    function init() {
        images = loadImages(['img/1.png', 'img/2.png'], main);    
    }

    function main() {  
        ctx.drawImage(images[1], 0,0);  
    }

    init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work better

```js
var images = ['img/1.png', 'img/2.png'], loadedImages = [], canvas,ctx, idx=0:
function main() {
  ctx.drawImage(images[1], 0, 0);
}

function loadImages() {
  if (loadedImages.length == images.length) {
    main();
    return;
  }
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    loadedImages.push(this);  
    loadImages();
    idx++;
  }
  image.src = imageFiles[idx];
}

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  loadImages();
}

window.onload = function() {
  init();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to push items into an array. Replace

```
loadedImages[i] = image;
```

with

```
loadedImages.push(image);
```

Comment: And what difference will this make ?