# 1 Load function for all images in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing loading image and hide it when the image is loaded.

```
$('.image1').on('load', function(){
    $('.image1').css("opacity","100");
    $('#loaderimg').hide();
});
```

However, I want to make this function for a specified div which contains some images. So the loader image should be shown until all images in div are loaded.

```
<div id="container">
  <img class="image1" src="land1.jpg" \>
  <img class="image2" src="land2.jpg" \>
  <img class="image3" src="land3.jpg" \>
  <img class="image4" src="land4.jpg" \>
</div>
```

The only thing is, there are maximum 4 images in the div, but sometimes it can be 1, 2, 3 or 4 images. But class names never change.

What is te correct approach to make it ?

Comment: [__Solution__](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36793583/1746830) I had posted long back may help!

Comment: Cool, but a bit sophisticated. Maybe comments in this topic more easier but does the same job ?

Comment: It certainly does..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track the loading of **all** images and only hide and show whenever all images are loaded. Maybe like this below.

But there are one thing left. What happens is a image is not availabe or has errors? You should track this too. Just add `error` to the listener.

And `opacity` can have a maximum of `1`, not `100`. And you can pass it as `float` or `number` instead of a `string`.

```
var images = $("#container img");
var amount = images.length;
var loaded = 0;

images.on("load error", function() {
    ++loaded;

    if( loaded == amount ) {
        images.css("opacity", 1);
        $('#loaderimg').hide();
    }
});
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/kbv1nw52/)**

Comment: Smart approach. Thanks.

Comment: There is a small misconfiguration here, maybe better to fix the name of "    ++laoded;" ;)

Comment: True @user3304007! Fixed.